# How to make a json_encode returned object into a javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am returning a `json_encode` object to an ajax call. First off, is there a better way to do this? Is this `json_encode needed?`

To the root of my question. When I try to get to make the key a variable, it throws a "not defined error". This line: `var displayTriggers = trigger_rows;`

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

PHP:

```
try {
    $con = getConfig('pdo');
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql_triggers = "
        SELECT *
        FROM triggers
    ";
    $triggers_stmt = $con->prepare($sql_triggers);
    $triggers_stmt->execute();
    $triggers_rows = $triggers_stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $triggers_arr = array();
    foreach ($triggers_rows as $triggers_row) {
        $trigger_id = $triggers_row['id'];
        $trigger_title = $triggers_row['trigger_name'];
        $trigger_setting = $triggers_row['setting'];
        $trigger_user = $triggers_row['user_id'];
        $trigger_placement = $triggers_row['placement'];
        $trigger_date = $triggers_row['date_changed'];
        $trigger_active = ( $trigger_setting == '1' ) ? ' active' : '';
        $html = '';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerRow" data-placement="'.$trigger_placement.'">';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerRowLeft">';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerTitle">' . $trigger_title . '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerText">' . $trigger_date . '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerText">' . $trigger_user . '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerRowRight">';
        $html .= '<div class="triggerButton' . $trigger_active . '"></div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $html .= '</div>';
        $data = array('html' => $html);
        $triggers_arr[] = $data;
    }
    echo json_encode(['trigger_rows' => $triggers_arr]);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

JS:

```
$wrapper = $('#triggerCont');
$.ajax({
    url: 'php/triggerSelect.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
      //console.log(data);
        if (data == null) {
            alert("Unable to retrieve triggers!");
            alert(data);
        } else {
            var displayTriggers = trigger_rows;
            $wrapper.empty();
            $(displayTriggers).each(function() {
                $wrapper.append(this.html);
                //console.log(this.html);
            });
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + " | " + errorThrown);
        alert('There are currently no project images for this selection');
    }
});
```

Comment: You get the data returned to the javascript in a variable called `data` from `success: function (data)` so try using `data.` rather than `trigger_rows`

Comment: Simple DEBUG idea. All browsers come with a debugger (F12). Load that and set a breakpoint on `if (data == null) {` and then check out what the object `data` actually contains

Comment: @RiggsFolly Doesn't this act as a breaking point though? `alert(data);` within the `data == null` statement?

Comment: It shows you data, stops the code executing while it does so. but as you are not in the debugger you cannot decide to step through the code line by line for example, also a good way to spot those little woopsies we all make

Comment: @Paul btw `alert(data)` when `data === null` is pointless, as it will alert null ;-) if you want to debug your db-php just return encoded json too like:`'error'=> true, 'message' => "..."` and check in js for `if(data.error)`

Comment: I definitely use the debugger all the time. I just didn't know enough about json to figure this out. Regarding the extended jscon_encode. Are you referring to something like this? If so, how would writing a key of 'error' and then making it true render an error? `echo json_encode(['trigger_rows' => $triggers_arr, 'error' => true, 'message' => "There was an issue with the data"]);`

Comment: Just to be sure: you've used the debugger, and you haven't seen that the variable `trigger_rows` has not been defined anywhere? After all, this problem is IMHO in no way connected to PHP, jQuery nor JSON

Comment: @NicoHaase I know the issue was directly related to `trigger_rows`...see my question: "To the root of my question. When I try to get to make the key a variable, it throws a "not defined error". This line: `var displayTriggers = trigger_rows;`" I wasn't sure what was causing the error, so I tagged in the pieces that made up the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var displayTriggers = data.trigger_rows;
```

should do the trick

Comment: Gotcha! I didn't even think about this. I used to do parse the data and use the obj, so just getting used to this method.

Comment: gotcha! Next time just check the console-output of the commented out `console.log(data)` , as you set dataType option to json it will automatically convert the string to json (json is already a js-object "stringified json" is just text)